# Django models. Retrieve the class of a model

Tags: django, django-models

there is a project where `models.py` looks like this:

```
class Page(models.Model)
    #fields

class News(Page)
    #no fields
```

When I want to retrieve a `Page` or a `News` page I do something like this:

`page = get_object_or_404(Page, id=page_id)`

However, when I give this: `page.__class__` I always get this: `main.models.Page`.

Is there a way to know if a page is actually a `Page` class or a `News` class without checking if `page_id` exists in `News`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given just the `page_id` value there is no way to test whether or not that ID value exists as an entry in the `News` table in addition to the `Page` table other than either trying to retrieve it (such as with `page.news`, and catching the `DoesNotExist` exception for cases in which it does not exist) or a direct query against the `News` manager.  Queries against the `Page` model's manager will return `Page` instances - you have to either know a priori in your view that you want `News` instead or test for existence.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at [isinstance](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance)

```
page = get_object_or_404(Page, id=page_id)    
isinstance(page, News):
```

Comment: This will never return `True`.  `get_object_or_404` will return an instance of the class you give it, if it returns anything rather than raising an exception.

Comment: Yes I misunderstood the question at first and also realized that this will not work because you are retrieving a Page object instance